# Project Dont Work after pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm creating a IOS application(https://github.com/felipeuntill/WeddingPlanner) and i currently trying to implement the login view using Firebase, my application is working normally but when i use the install command my app crashes with this message:

```
ld: framework not found Pods_WeddingPlanner
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What i'm doing:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/felipeuntill/WeddingPlanner.git
$ cd WeddingPlanner
// The App sucessfull build.
$ pod init
// Edit podfile and add reference to 'Firebase' and 'Firebase/Auth'.
$ pod install 
// The app build crashes.
```

The entire error message:

```
Ld /Users/felipeassuncao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingPlanner-dozgfwtyrufjmheoacfbfkuseaar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingPlanner.app/WeddingPlanner normal x86_64
    cd /Users/felipeassuncao/Development/Projects/WeddingPlanner/IOS
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/felipeassuncao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingPlanner-dozgfwtyrufjmheoacfbfkuseaar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/felipeassuncao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingPlanner-dozgfwtyrufjmheoacfbfkuseaar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/felipeassuncao/Development/Projects/WeddingPlanner/IOS/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/felipeassuncao/Development/Projects/WeddingPlanner/IOS/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks -F/Users/felipeassuncao/Development/Projects/WeddingPlanner/IOS/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/felipeassuncao/Development/Projects/WeddingPlanner/IOS/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/felipeassuncao/Development/Projects/WeddingPlanner/IOS/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/felipeassuncao/Development/Projects/WeddingPlanner/IOS/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/felipeassuncao/Development/Projects/WeddingPlanner/IOS/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -filelist /Users/felipeassuncao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingPlanner-dozgfwtyrufjmheoacfbfkuseaar/Build/Intermediates/WeddingPlanner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingPlanner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WeddingPlanner.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.3 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework CoreGraphics -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleNetworkingUtilities -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/felipeassuncao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingPlanner-dozgfwtyrufjmheoacfbfkuseaar/Build/Intermediates/WeddingPlanner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingPlanner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WeddingPlanner.swiftmodule -framework Pods_WeddingPlanner -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/felipeassuncao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingPlanner-dozgfwtyrufjmheoacfbfkuseaar/Build/Intermediates/WeddingPlanner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingPlanner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WeddingPlanner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/felipeassuncao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingPlanner-dozgfwtyrufjmheoacfbfkuseaar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingPlanner.app/WeddingPlanner

ld: framework not found Pods_WeddingPlanner
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you execute pod install, you should alway open up your project by using WeddingPlanner.xcworkspace, never use WeddingPlanner.xcodeproj

Answer (score 1):

Open your .xcworkspace file not xcodeproj and Clean your project and build again